# Taking an image and converting it into BLOB for MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, encoding, type-conversion, blob

I am trying to make a JavaScript that would take an image file and covert it into BLOB (by converting the file into Base64 first and then into BLOB), my project doesn't have a support for toBlob() so I have found different convering steps and put them together and they work to a point where I have to pass the BLOB from the function where its made out for the Mysql part of code that takes care of communicating with the database. (I have that fully working). Now I only need to find a way how to connect them through a variable that saves the results of the `imageforQuery` function.

My code so far is this:

```
  let base64String = "";

  function imageforQuery(imageid) {
          //takes file and converts to Base64
          var file = document.getElementById(imageid).files[0];

          var reader = new FileReader();
          console.log("next");
          imgFileFrontBlob = "";
          reader.onload = function () {
              base64String = reader.result.replace("data:", "")
                  .replace(/^.+,/, "");

              // console.log(base64String);
              base64String = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ base64String;
              console.log(base64String);
              //converts Base64 into BLOB
              var binary = atob(base64String.split(',')[1]);
              console.log(binary);
              var array = [];
              for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
                  array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
              }
              var imgFileFrontBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/png'});

              console.log(imgFileFrontBlob);
              return imgFileFrontBlob

          }

          reader.readAsDataURL(file);


       };
```

by experimenting with `console.log()` at different stages and `return` I have found out that I can't pass the converted BLOB result out, as the function `imageforQuery()` only returns what is after `reader.readAsDataURL(file);` and I don't know of a way of getting that result out.

––––––––––––––ADDITIONAL PROBLEMS I HAVE ENCOUNTERED––––––––––––––

okay so thanks to Emiel Zuurbier (Thank you!) I have managed to rewrite my code with the help of his solution. However as much as it helped one part of the problem, it didn't help with the JavaScript `Blob object` as we found out it is not the exact same thing as SQL `BLOB`.

Now the problem is that upon trying to send the `Blob object` in a SQL query, this resulted in just sending pure text "[Blob object]".

But I am using JavaScript successfully to pull the data from a BLOB field from my database and convert it into `Base64` images from that data that was stored in the `BLOB` in a different part of my application. The code for that is below:

```
var converterEngine = function (input) { 
   // fn BLOB => Binary => Base64 ?
   var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(input),
      i = uInt8Array.length;
   var biStr = []; //new Array(I);
   while (i--) { biStr[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);  }
   var base64 = window.btoa(biStr.join(''));
   return base64;
};
```

What I need to do is just reverse this and in theory, it should get me the same data that I receive from the database.
My reversal code is below:

```
// this is the inside bit of code from the first problem that is solved and the 
// typeOfData variable is parsed into the function in imageforQuery() as a second input 
// variable (in other words its not to be of concern)
reader.onload = function () {
          let base64String = reader.result.replace("data:", "").replace(/^.+,/, "");
          base64String = "data:" + typeOfData + ";base64," + base64String;

          var binary = atob(base64String.split(",")[1]);
          // console.log(binary);
          var array = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
            array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
          }
          var ourArray = new Uint8Array(array);
          



          resolve(ourArray);
        };
```

However, as I mentioned the data that comes out (`ourArray`) isn't actually identical to the original file from the BLOB in the database so my code doesn't function correctly and I don't know why. Any ideas where I've made a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `FileReader` instance and calls inside of a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Return the `Promise` immediately. In the `reader.onload` function call `resolve()` to exit the `Promise` with a value.

```
function imageforQuery(imageid) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var file = document.getElementById(imageid).files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
  
    reader.onload = function () {
      let base64String = reader.result.replace("data:", "").replace(/^.+,/, "");
      base64String = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;

      var binary = atob(base64String.split(",")[1]);
      var array = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
      }

      var imgFileFrontBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
        type: "image/png",
      });
  
      resolve(imgFileFrontBlob);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}
```

This results in being able to use your function like here below. `imageforQuery` is called, returns a `Promise`. When the promise is finished (meaning `resolve` is called) the function in the `then` method will run.

```
imageforQuery(imageId).then(imgFileFrontBlob => {
  // Use your blob here.
  saveToDB(imgFileFrontBlob); // Example of how you would use it.
});
```

Or use it with `async` / `await`.

```
(async () => {
  function imageforQuery(imageid) {
    ...
  }

  // Here we can wait for imageforQuery to finish and save the variable.
  const imgFileFrontBlob = await imageforQuery(imageId);
  saveToDB(imgFileFrontBlob); // Example of how you would use it.
})()
```

Comment: I need to be able to send the blob out into the database in a SQL query, but if I use ```var imgFileFrontBlob = imageforQuery(imageId)```, what gets passed into the database is only a string saying ```[object Promise]``` and not the actual blob, in what way can I use the ```then``` method?

Comment: In the second code snippet you can see how you use that `Promise` that is returned. I've added links to documentation on how Promises work.

Comment: If I put all my MySQL code for sending out the data to DB inside that ```imageforQuery(imageId).then(imgFileFrontBlob => {
``` it still only saves a string "```[object Blob]```" with no actual data in it.

Comment: And it is not suitable for me to make a ```saveToDB()``` function as I am converting and sending three different files so what I really need is to just have that conversion function that I can then call out three times for each file, each giving me a variable (with a blob stored in it) all of which I can then put into my main code that is responsible for sending the information into the database. I wrote the conversion function, it just doesn't pass the blob out. That's what I need.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. A [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) is a JavaScript object. It's not the same as a BLOB in SQL. So you can't just copy one over to the other. Whatever you're using is converting the blob object to a string which gives you `[object Blob]`. You can however get the content of the `Blob` as a string with [`Blob.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text).

Comment: It is possible that I misunderstood it... But In my other parts of the code where I am requesting the image (I get data from the  BLOB column of data -> convert it into Base64 and then I display that in HTML) and the  reversed process works without a problem and my JavaScript processes the BLOB data as binary data I think(?) Here's the reversal process:

Comment: ```var converterEngine = function (input) { // fn BLOB => Binary => Base64
                    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(input),
                          i = uInt8Array.length;
                    var biStr = []; //new Array(i);
                    while (i--) { biStr[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);  }
                    var base64 = window.btoa(biStr.join(''));
                    return base64;
                };```

Comment: I looked up what kind of data a BLOB in SQL is. Turns out its either a binary or character string based on the type of content. The `FileReader` object also has a method called [`.readAsBinaryString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString), which might already provide the conversion you require to be able to store it as a Blob. Otherwise look into the [Blob.text()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text) method which returns your BLOB data as an UTF-8 encoded string, which should also work.

Comment: well, is there at least any way how to get a variable out to become a general variable? I know that if I set ```var example = "this is an example" ``` it is only a local variable and for a function to set a global variable I would have to write it as ```example = "this is an example" ```, however that doesn't work for the code that converts the different types of data for some reason (neither the Base64, nor the binary, nothing that is inside the ```Promise```. You told me that I can use the ```then``` method and I tried to look it up but I don't understand it one bit.

Comment: I am not a coder, I am doing this more just on a whim, because I need to make an app for my grandad, so my knowledge of JavaScript is pretty much zero, I only understand the general basis of coding and as much as I tried to read through the documentation it's confusing me. But I know that if I can get either the JavaScript or any parts of the other types of data out of the promise, I am able to work with that. the Blob.text() somewhat works, as it does convert the ```object Blob ``` into a string but that is still kept inside the ```then``` method and cant make it a general variable as I need

Comment: I understand and see that the docs can be confusing. Let's take it step by step. You want to extract the returnd value from the function. The only way that is possible is by using `async/await`. This adds a syntax in which you can tell your code to wait for a function to finish before continuing. To do this, you'll need to wrap your code inside an async function. I've added an example which demonstrates this. This is need because of the asynchronous nature of the filereader, (which takes a bit of time to finish and doesn't want the rest of your browser code to stop running). Please try it out.

Comment: Okay, now that somewhat helped! I understand now how to use the async/await and I can get the variable out and use it as I need and I am able to use it for multiple different files. Which is great! the next issue now is the ```Blob object``` still doesn't get sent. I took a reverse problem-solving approach to this: I have a code that takes ```BLOB``` (SQL data) and converts it into ```binary``` and then into ```Base64```. And I tried to figure out what the insides do to reverse it exactly, but the data seem to be different to the original. I'll update the post here to reflect that next part.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is simply ascii text.  So MySQL's datatype `BLOB` or `TEXT` would work.  That is, after converting to Base64, don't worry about "convert to blob"; it is not necessary.

That is, you can probably replace the code from `//converts ...` through `return ...` by simply

```
return base64String;
```

Comment: I am aware of that. However my reasoning using ```BLOB```s is that it's easier to work with ```BLOB```s in MySQL Workbench if I need to make changes to the database manually.